# Path drawing with d3?

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I'm trying to use d3 to generate path and set color by dataset. Color of path is set by "Req" and drawing path by set of point but i get some parsing problem when getting data back. My data format showed as below.

```
var feature = {"section":[
  {"ID": 1,"Req": 10,"Name": "Jame","point": [{"x": 1,"y": 1},{"x": 5,"y": 5},{"x": 20,"y": 30},{"x": 200,"y": 200}]},
  {"ID": 2,"Req": 20,"Name": "John","point": [{"x": 1,"y": 1},{"x": 7,"y": 10},{"x": 100,"y": 10},{"x": 20,"y": 200}]}  
]};
```

In order to get coordinate of x and y in dataset,I have function of line generator as following by

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
     .interpolate("linear")
     .x(function(d) { d.point.forEach(function(a){ return a.x;});})
     .y(function(d) { d.point.forEach(function(a){ return a.y;});});
```

I set style color of path with value of "Req" in dataset.

```
canvas.selectAll("path")
    .data(feature.section)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("d", line(feature.section))
    .attr("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", function(d) {
       var returnColor;
       if (d.Req > 5){returnColor ="green";}
       else if (d.Req > 10){returnColor ="purple";}
       else if (d.Req > 15){returnColor ="red";}
       else{returnColor = "#ccc";}
       return returnColor;
    });
```

But I have no line showed on the screen.  The debugging console always showed Error: Problem parsing d="MNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaNLNaN,NaN"

Did I miss something?

You also see my example of this code on http://jsfiddle.net/agadoo/RZQxV/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to draw several paths, one for each request ID. What you need in this case are [nested selections](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nest/).

To draw a path, you would pass an array to the `.data()` function and give `x` and `y` functions in your `d3.svg.line()` definition to extract the relevant datum from each element of that array. That is, the functions you specify there should return the `x` and `y` coordinates for exactly one point. So you would change them to be something like

```
.x(function(d) { return d.x; })
```

I've modified your jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/RZQxV/2/). Note that in this scenario you can't get the color for the lines in the same way that you did it anymore because that data is not available at that level. There're several ways to overcome this, the most straightforward is probably to reformat your data. The d3 array functions (in particular the [`d3.nest()` functions](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#wiki-d3_nest)) should be helpful here.

On a final note, your checks to set the color of the line won't work as you expect. `d.Req > 5` will be true if `d.Req > 10`, so your second and third conditions will never be met as they are already covered by the first one.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try nest function.